# QLPreviewController loses touch after presenting a modal view controller over it

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

In an iPad master-detail application (the master is an `UITableViewController` and the detail a `QLPreviewController`) whenever I present a view controller modally **and then dismiss it**, the `QLPreviewController` stops receiving touch events or at least reacting to them. So, it's no longer possible to zoom in or out, or "bouncing" an image/document currently being shown, even after another image/document is selected and shown.

Keep in mind that before presenting the view controller modally everything works as expected and it's possible to zoom in/out.

Anyone knows a possible solution for this weird problem?

EDIT: added that this happens after dismissing the view controller presented modally.

EDIT 2: if the presentation style is `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, the problem does not occur. It seems to only occur with `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a solution for this problem, a workaround is to present the view controller as UIModalPresentationFormSheet instead of fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is expected behaviour.

When a ViewController is presented modally (I assume you are presenting something in a form sheet?), it prevents other view controllers receiving touch events.

The other alternative is to have a look at [child view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) as an alternative; but again, their touch events will take precedence over anything underneath.

Comment: Is there an expected specific behaviour you are after?

Comment: I forgot to add that this happens after the view controller has been dismissed. (I'm presenting it fullscreen, but I'll try to present it as sheet to see if it makes any difference.)

Comment: If I present the view controller with UIModalPresentationFormSheet style, then the problem no longer happens.